# How to write to multiple files in Python?

Tags: python, file

I have two files I want to open:

```
file = open('textures.txt', 'w')
file = open('to_decode.txt', 'w')
```

Then I want to write to both of them separately:

```
file.write("Username: " + username + " Textures: " + textures)
file.write(textures)
```

The first write thing is for the first open and the second is for the second.
How would I do this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Use two different variable names. Also `file` is a bad choice. It's the name of a builtin function in Python 2.

Comment: file1 and file2 or you can write a function and do the open and write in the function so you don't have to repeat yourself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the `file` variable with the second open, so all the writes would be directed there. Instead, you should use two variables:

```
textures_file = open('textures.txt', 'w')
decode_file = open('to_decode.txt', 'w')

textures_file.write("Username: " + username + " Textures: " + textures)
decode_file.write(textures)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use "with" to avoid mentioning file.close() explicitly. Then You don't have to close it - Python will do it automatically either during garbage collection or at program exit.

```
with open('textures.txt', 'w') as file1,open('to_decode.txt', 'w') as file2:

    file1.write("Username: " + username + " Textures: " + textures)
    file2.write(textures)
```

Comment: Yet the main advantage of `with` is the automatic closing of the file handle even when an error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Name your file pointers two different things, i.e. not both "file".

```
file1 = open...
file2 = open...

file1.write...
file2.write...
```

Right now, the second "file" declaration you're making is over-writing the first one, so file only points to "to_decode.txt".

Answer (score 0):

Just give them different names:

```
f1 = open('textures.txt', 'w')
f2 = open('to_decode.txt', 'w')

f1.write("Username: " + username + " Textures: " + textures)
f2.write(textures)
```

As others have mentioned, file is the name of a built-in function so using that name for your local variable is a bad choice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two different variables, as @Klaus says, to create two different, distinct handles to which you can push operations. So,

```
file1 = open('textures.txt', 'w')
file2 = open('to_decode.txt', 'w')
```

then

```
file1.write("Username: " + username + " Textures: " + textures)
file2.write(textures)
```